# Stored Procedure with Volatile Tables and input parameter

Tags: teradata

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that gathers some data into various (2) volatile tables, then outputs a result set based on a query from those volatile tables.

I think I've got the syntax written correctly, but when I call the procedure (call msn_test ('2018-05-01','510001')), it returns 0 results. I believe it has something to do with the way the variables are being parsed.

Here is a sample of my table structure

```
create VOLATILE TABLE  customer_count  (
cust_no varchar(10)
,ordercount int
,rpt_mth date
)  on commit preserve rows;

INSERT INTO customer_count VALUES ('510001', '502','2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO customer_count VALUES ('510002', '2','2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO customer_count VALUES ('510003', '100','2018-05-01');

create VOLATILE TABLE  customer_sales  (
cust_no varchar(10)
,revenue decimal(15,2)
,rpt_mth date
)  on commit preserve rows;

INSERT INTO customer_sales VALUES ('510001', '12500','2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO customer_sales VALUES ('510002', '5000','2018-05-01');
INSERT INTO customer_sales VALUES ('510003', '1400','2018-05-01');
```

Here is my stored procedure as being executed-

```
create VOLATILE TABLE tmp_one (cust_no varchar(30), ordercount int)  on commit preserve rows;
create VOLATILE TABLE tmp_two (cust_no varchar(30),revenue decimal(18,2)) on commit preserve rows;

replace procedure msn_test (
IN mth date,
IN cust varchar(30))
dynamic result sets 1

begin

declare rslt cursor with return only for

select
a.cust_no, a.ordercount, b.revenue
from tmp_one a
join tmp_two b
    on a.cust_no = b.cust_no
    ;


call dbc.SysExecSQL('create VOLATILE TABLE tmp_one as (select cust_no, sum(ordercount) ordercount   from customer_count where cust_no = ''' || cust || ''' and rpt_mth = cast(''' || mth ||''' as date)    group by 1) with data on commit preserve rows');
call dbc.SysExecSQL('create VOLATILE TABLE tmp_two as (select cust_no, sum(revenue) revenue             from customer_sales  where cust_no = ''' || cust || ''' and rpt_mth = cast(''' || mth ||''' as date)    group by 1) with data on commit preserve rows');


open rslt;
 drop table tmp_one;
 drop table tmp_two;
end;
  drop table tmp_one;
drop table tmp_two;
```

And finally, here is my sp call but I get no results.

```
call msn_test ('2018-05-01','510001')
```

And this is my wanted outcome -

```
    cust_no ordercount  revenue
 1  510001  502         12,500.00
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you need to create your volatile tables before you declare your cursor (inside your proc).  Although I really don't see why you need volatile tables here.

Comment: When I run your code I get your *wanted outcome* :)

Comment: @Andrew Well this scenario is greatly simplified. Obviously it wouldn't make sense to copy from one small table to another. This was just an example of me needing to aggregate several tables of data, and then combine at the end.

Comment: @dnoeth Could this have something to do with different versions or something? I literally just ran this, and I get no results..... i dont understand.

Comment: Don't drop the VTs, check the data and run the Select after the CALL. What is your session mode Teradata or ANSI?

Comment: so my VT's are empty, which makes me think its something with the way my param's are being parsed. I am in Teradata mode.